# Show a form field on keyup

Tags: javascript, onkeyup

I'm trying for the life of me to show a hidden field in a form with a specific input (numbers 4 and higher).

JS:

```
function showStuff(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
}
```

HTML:

```
<tr valign="top">
    <td <? if(strstr($Error,"intern_openings")){ ?> class="error" <? } ?>>*Number of Interns/<br>Available positions:</td>
    <td colspan="2"><input type="text" name="intern_openings" size="3" maxlength="3" value="<?=$intern_openings?>" onkeyup="javascript:showStuff('supervisorname')"><br />
    <div id="supervisorname" style="display:none;">
    <br />
        Names of intern supervisors (employer staff):<br />
        <input type="text" name="supervisor[]" value="<?=$supervisor?>" <? if(strstr($supervisorList)){ ?> <? } ?>><br />
        <input type="text" name="supervisor[]" value="<?=$supervisor?>" <? if(strstr($supervisorList)){ ?> <? } ?>><br />
        <input type="text" name="supervisor[]" value="<?=$supervisor?>" <? if(strstr($supervisorList)){ ?> <? } ?>><br />
        <input type="text" name="supervisor[]" value="<?=$supervisor?>" <? if(strstr($supervisorList)){ ?> <? } ?>>
    </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Any insight would be totally radical.

Comment: Question not constructed properly

Comment: Could you please clarify the question and perhaps include a bit more of the code?

Comment: hidden field means? `input type="hidden"` or `style="display:none"`

Comment: sorry all...here's the HTML TR to TR:

Comment: looks like it's the div that is div that is hidden, not the input field

Comment: Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/NSL8P/

Comment: it does work, but i would like the fields to appear upon entering the numbers 4 and higher...

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/NSL8P/1/ ?

Comment: AHHH! That's the little snippet I was looking for! Many thanks j08691!